# How can I update a single API request in AngularJS to pass different Query parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, rest

I'm using AngularJS to pull posts from a REST API on WordPress.com.

I want to parse the post data by category into three sections.

I was able to create an App that displays posts properly, but it uses multiple `$http.get` commands to get posts in each section. This results in a very slow App with lots of redundancy.

How can I eliminate redundancy and speed up my App? Is there any way to write several different controllers that update a single API request?

Here's my AngularJS code:

```
//Initialize My Angular App
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//Create Controllers
app.controller('seeDoInNewOrleansCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/www.gonola.com/posts?category=see-do-in-new-orleans&number=1')
        .success(function (response) {
        $scope.postData = response;
    });
});
app.controller('eatDrinkInNewOrleansCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/www.gonola.com/posts?category=eat-drink-in-new-orleans&number=1')
        .success(function (response) {
        $scope.postData = response;
    });
});
app.controller('musicCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/www.gonola.com/posts?category=music&number=1')
        .success(function (response) {
        $scope.postData = response;
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle of myApp: https://jsfiddle.net/tr0sdky1/

Answer (score 0):

The trivial answer would be combine the 3 into one controller, and instead of using $scope.postData for all of them use `$scope.postDataSee` for the 1st, `$scope.postDataEat` for the 2nd, and `$scope.postDataMusic` for the 3rd, with the respective ng-repeat using the different scope variables.

The less trivial answer would be combine the 3 requests using promises and $q all, and then use one repeater to go over them all.

/

```
/Initialize My Angular App
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    //Create Controller
    app.controller('postsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $q) {

        var categories = ['See & Do', 'Eat & Drink', 'Music'];

        var seePromise = $http.get('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/www.gonola.com/posts?category=see-do-in-new-orleans&number=1');
        var eatPromise = $http.get('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/www.gonola.com/posts?category=eat-drink-in-new-orleans&number=1');
        var musicPromise = $http.get('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/www.gonola.com/posts?category=music&number=1');

        $q.all([seePromise, eatPromise, musicPromise).then(function(results) {
            $scope.posts = results;
        });

    });
```

And the pseudo html:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <span>{{category}}</span> <!-- Category name and whatever... -->
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts[$index]">
        <!-- post data -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is just going to be of the same effect. Split into multiple controllers also makes ajax calls parallel (or somewhat). i think if the api supports one network call to fetch all the data that would be ideal perhaps.

Comment: The WordPress API stores all the post data in one place (ie- https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/www.gonola.com/posts) .. But I don't know how to query the API a single time, then use the query parameters to segment the posts for display.